# I want to know what is the functionality of the following code

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am trying to understand what the following jquery code will return?

```
$(`:contains("keyword"):not(:has(:contains("keyword")))`)
```

Comment: Don't you think it would be best to read some of the `jQuery` documentation to find the answer you are looking for?

Comment: I have tried but I am confused.

Comment: Which part are you confused about?

Comment: I understand it now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/):

> Description: Selects elements which contain at least one element that matches the specified selector.
>
> The expression `$( "div:has(p)" )` matches a  if a `<p>` exists anywhere among its descendants, not just as a direct child.

So, `:contains("keyword"):not(:has(:contains("keyword")))` will select an element which contains `keyword`, but does not have any *descendants* which contain `keyword`. In other word, the `keyword` must be in the parent, but not in any of the parent's children. For example:

```js
const match = $(`div:contains("keyword"):not(:has(:contains("keyword")))`);
console.log(match.length);
console.log(match[0]);
console.log(match[1]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1" class="outer">
  keyword
  <div id="2" class="inner">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="3" class="outer">
  <div id="4" class="inner">
    keyword
  </div>
</div>
```

It selects the first `.outer` because `.outer` has an immediate *text node* descendant with `keyword`. It selects the second `.inner` because it also has an immediate *text node* descendant with `keyword`.

The selector requires that `keyword` is in a text node which is a child of the parent element selected.

You could emulate the selector with vanilla DOM methods like this:

```js
const match = [...document.querySelectorAll('div')]
  .filter(
    elm => [...elm.childNodes]
      .filter(({ nodeType }) => nodeType === 3) // Only look through text nodes
      .some(({ textContent }) => textContent.includes('keyword'))
  );
console.log(match.length);
console.log(match[0]);
console.log(match[1]);
```

```html
<div id="1" class="outer">
  keyword
  <div id="2" class="inner">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="3" class="outer">
  <div id="4" class="inner">
    keyword
  </div>
</div>
```